# Linear Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let Q : V → V be a projection, namely Q ◦ Q = Q

Exhibit a basis E = {$e_1, . . . e_n$} and a k ∈ {1, . . . , n} such that

[image: Picture of Matrix Block]

where $I_k ∈ M_{k×k} $ is the identity matrix, and the other blocks are $k × (n − k),(n − k) × k,(n − k) ×
(n − k) $ matrices of zeroes.

Assuming the above refers to cross product my thought was to do the following:

$|k||n-k|sin(\theta) = 0$

$|n-k||k|sin(\theta) = 0$

$|n-k||n-k|sin(\theta) = 0$

One way to be sure all the above criteria hold is to have $sin(\theta) = 0$. That happens, for example, when $k$ and $n-k$ are the same direction. Therefore, $n= 2k$.
And a basis could be {$e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$} and $k=2$.

I am still feeling quite uncertain with my grasp of linear algebra concepts thus far. I suspect I am missing a point in a big way. I would appreciate any feedback and guidance. Thank you.

Comment: No, that doesn’t refer to cross products. It is the dimensions of the matrix blocks.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us see that $Qx = x$ for $x\in Im(Q)$. Indeed, if $x\in Im(Q)$, then $x = Qu$. Hence, $Qx = Q^2u = Qu = x$. We further have
$$
V = Im(Q)\oplus\ker(Q).
$$
Why? Well, each $x\in V$ can be written as $x = Qx + (I-Q)x$. Surely, $Qx\in Im(Q)$ and $Q(I-Q)x = (Q-Q^2)x = 0$, hence $(I-Q)x\in\ker Q$. To see that the sum is direct, let $x\in Im(Q)\cap\ker(Q)$. Then $Qx = 0$, but also $Qx = x$, so $x=0$.

Now, choose a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ of $Im(Q)$ and a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-k}\}$ of $\ker(Q)$. Then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,w_1,\ldots,w_{n-k}\}$ is a basis of $V$ due to the above decomposition of $V$. We have $Qv_j = v_j$ for all $j$ and $Qw_l = 0$ for all $l$. Hence, the matrix representation of $Q$ is as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am so confused still. I've been reading and rereading your reply. Could you elaborate further at all? Why is it that choosing a basis for the kernel and image solves the problem? How did you know to decompose it? Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand in my text?

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: The task is to find a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,w_1,\ldots,w_{n-k}\}$ of $V$ such that $Qv_j = v_j$ for all $j$ and $Qw_l = 0$ for all $l$. To understand why that is the task you should read about matrix representations of linear transforms with respect to a basis.

Comment: How is it the cross products are related? And {$v_1, ... , v_k, w_1, ..., w_{n-k}$} is already expressed with respect to E?

Comment: What cross product??? And the basis I gave you _is_ $E$ (or at least serves as an example for $E$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67154/discussion-between-sofia-and-amsmath).

Answer (score 1):

I think we're from the same algebra class! Yayy! I will just add some points based on amsmath's answer.

The question says if we have $Q◦Q=Q$, then $Q_E^E$ will be a weird matrix shown in the problem. And now, find a basis of V, and show $Q_E^E$ indeed looks like that.

1. First, the sign $\times$ doesn't mean cross products! For example, $k\times(n-k)$ simply means one block in the graph has $k$ rows and $n-k$ columns.
2. From $Q◦Q=Q$, we have the fact, $V = N(Q) ⊕ R(Q)$. I guess you've known it!

And now the problem is, if we know V can be written as a decomposition of $N(Q)$ and $R(Q)$, how will you construct a basis for V? Refer to amsmath's answer. =)

3. dim(V) = n, assume dim(R(Q))=k, then dim(N(Q)) is n-k. Then naturally, we construct the basis of the range, R=$\{v_1,…,v_k\}$, and the basis of the kernel, $K=\{w_1,…,w_{n−k}\}$. And the basis of V is $\{v_1,…,v_k,w_1,…,w_{n−k}\}$.

Now how to compute $Q_E^E$? 
We basically apply the projection on each of the element in the basis, and see what it looks like in terms of $\{v_1,…,v_k,w_1,…,w_{n−k}\}$.

4. What's $Q_{w_j}$ where $w_j\in K$? Easy to answer!
5. What's $Q_{v_j}$ where $v_j\in R$? Think about $Q◦Q=Q$!